# getAllVoiceShortcuts function returns twice

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirishortcuts

I'm fetching voiceShortcurts related with my app. Below function goes into completion block twice. It returns true at first, then false which true is the right one. Why It goes into completion block twice?

```
 public static func updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: @escaping ((_ haveShortcutAlready: Bool) -> Void)) {
        INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts { (voiceShortcutsFromCenter, error) in
            if let voiceShortcutsFromCenter = voiceShortcutsFromCenter {
                self.voiceShortcuts = voiceShortcutsFromCenter
                    completion(true)
            } else {
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    print(error)
                }
                    completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```